# Get View from the OnTouch Method from superClass when define Views Programmatically

Tags: android

I have a superClass "Central" with a button and OnTouchListener(View v, MotionEvent event) method. "Lay1" is an activity subclass of "Central" and use addView() to make appear button on layout. The addView() works fine but I obtain 0 value when I try to get the v.getX() or all v methods. I know that the activity can't "see" this "v" because is implemented and when I call v, this not already exists. I need a @override method to give-me back the "v" but I don't know where I place that. Thank you for helping

Comment: You can easily get the view from the super class, but first you have to inflate the view in the activity. Second it's depends over the view variable access type defined to the variable or just create the method to get this view. Also you get the width or height of an view zero until it get inflated.

Comment: Also, to get the view width etc use yourView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // Ensure you call it only once :
            yourView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

            // Here you can get the size :)
        }
    });

Comment: To get the view like width and height works fine. But to return v.getX or v.getY for example, this method returns 0. Any Idea of another method to obtain this? Thanks

Comment: Use view.getwidth() and view.getHeight() methods instead.